# Correcting ImageField link

Tags: python, django, django-settings, imagefield

Using django 1.8 I have

```
# model.py
def signatures_path(instance, filename):
    return '{}/signatures/{}/{}'\
        .format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.id, filename)


class Des(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    signature = models.ImageField(upload_to=signatures_path,\
        blank=True, null=True, default=None)


# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# urls.py : I've included this pattern
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
```

The admin page produces this link:
http://192.168.155.44:8000/home/max/myapp/myapp/media/signatures/1/sig.png
which does not work but I can view the image at
http://192.168.155.44:8000/media/signatures/1/sig.png

How can I fix it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify absolute path:

```
def signatures_path(instance, filename):
    return 'signatures/{}/{}'.format(instance.id, filename)
```

Django will use `MEDIA_ROOT` by default.

Also you don't need a separate `url` to serve media files, django dev server knows how to handle those. On production server though, say if you'll be using apache, you will have to configure apache to serve media and static files.

Comment: Works perfectly. I had to reload the images. Thanks.